# Calculate value in tooltip in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js

I'm using chartJS to display data with 2 or sometimes 3 datasets.

Can I make it so it shows not only `tooltipItem.yLabel`, but also a percentage of total amount of `yLabel (dataset1/(dataset1+dataset2))`?
I want to put this value in `afterLabel`.

ChartJS options code:

```
tooltips : {

    callbacks : {

        label : function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        },
        afterLabel : function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return dataset1/(dataset1+dataset2);
        },
    }
}
```

My 'Y' datasets are arrays of numbers.
X dataset is array of dates.
I can't seem to figure out how chart.min.js takes these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted, thank you @Kubilay Karpat for bringing me to an idea how to find needed values. I would +rep you, but I don't have enough to do so.

```
afterLabel : function(tooltipItem, data) {
    var total = 0;
    total = parseInt(data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index]) + parseInt(data.datasets[1].data[tooltipItem.index]);                    
    var percentage = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] / total * 100;
    var percentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
    return percentage + " %";
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. All you need to do is traverse all datasets and sum the values that corresponds your index number. Then you can divide your number to this sum. Following code works for me:

```
afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data){
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
    total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
  }
  var percentage = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] / total * 100;
  var percentage = percentage.toFixed(2); // Trim decimal part
  return "Percentage: %" + percentage;
}
```

Also, following part seems like redundant, since this the default pattern of tooltip label.

```
label : function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
    },
```

And if you like to trim/floor/ceil the percentage like in my example you might want to consider the fact that sums of percentages might not be equal to 100 in your graph.

Comment: Thanks for effort, but that's not exactly what I need.
As I said, I have 2 datasets. So each day, there are 2 points on Y axis.
I want label to say Y point1 hover / (Y point1 hover + Y point2) * 100.
So, basically, it should be Y point1% + Y point2% == 100%